# How high can the Black Tentacles spell reach?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, area-of-effect, 3d-space

The spell [Black Tentacles](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/blackTentacles.html) does not say how high they can reach up. Could it grab some Stirges that fly over the area of effect for example?

Comment: There's a remarkable lack of information about the third dimension in the area info for spells... http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html#area

Comment: This is why we had a heated discussion in our last session.

Comment: There's a bit more clarification in the SRD but only for spheres; http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/area-effect-diagrams

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it could, unless the stirges are flying over 20' high - at the spells centrepoint anyway.

The [SRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) clarifies that any spell with a radius extends into the third dimension in a similar fashion.

[Black tentacles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/black-tentacles) has a 20' radius of effect and only effects creatures in the area of effect, therefore as long as the stirges have room to fly above that height they're safe, otherwise they're going to get grabbed.

Since the effect is a sphere they *could* squeeze past in a corner if there's room, I'd give them a flying roll for this to not miss a flap and become tenticalificed.

This does create another question however, how high do spells extend if they have an area of effect but don't have a radius (looking through a load of AOE spells they seem to have done a good job of covering this actually, most spells have a height specified or are a radius effect)
Maybe I need a question "how high is a square?"

Comment: FWIW, my groups have homeruled that the 20ft is a hard 20ft up for the entire radius of the spell (so its essentially cylindrical) and nobodies had issues with that ruling; it's easy to adjudicate so it doesn't take up too much extra time on a spell that already slows down play.