# Can you misty step over an enemy and then fall down?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, teleportation, falling

Can you just use *misty step* to teleport over someone and then let yourself fall down? Or is the "space above someone" also occupied if he just stands on the ground? What's the RAW here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Yes, you can *misty step* above someone.

There is nothing in the rules preventing this. *Misty step* says:

> Briefly surrounded by silvery mist, you teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space that you can see.

If you can see the unoccupied space, you can teleport to it. The trouble is adjudicating what happens when you fall onto another creature.

#### *Tasha's Cauldron* adds an optional rule

What I describe towards the end is how I have done it for a while now, but *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* introduces an optional rule:

> If a creature falls into the space of a second creature and neither of them is Tiny, the second creature must succeed on a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw or be impacted by the falling creature, and any damage resulting from the fall is divided evenly between them. The impacted creature is also knocked prone, unless it is two or more sizes larger than the falling creature.

I cannot speak from experience concerning this rule, as I have not used it yet at the table.

#### In my experience.

The rules are pretty silent concerning 3d space. Prior to *Tasha's*, there was nothing in the core rules to help us adjudicate the spaces above the ground, so the DM needed to work with the players to determine how to rule this. This silence has led to such Q&As as this one: [Does the Evard's Black Tentacles spell affect the 5-foot cubes above its area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174469/does-the-evards-black-tentacles-spell-affect-the-5-foot-cubes-above-its-area)

In my games, I have allowed exactly the scenario you describe - using *misty step* or *dimension door* to teleport directly above an enemy. In these scenarios, I give the creature on the ground DC 10 dexterity saving throw to take full or half the falling damage the falling creature takes. I use DC 10 because it makes for a pretty easy save, and discourages abuse. My players have always enjoyed doing this and have never taken to abusing it.

So for example, if you use *misty step* to teleport 30 feet above a creature and fall onto them, they make a DC 10 dexterity save, taking 3d6 on a failure, or half that on a success. I've always used a quick Pythagorean Theorem calculation to determine how high you can appear based on how far away from the target creature you are when you *misty step*. The formula is:

$$\sqrt{900-d^2}.$$

Where \$d\$ is the ground distance from the creature you are trying to fall on. Here is a quick reference table with the distances I have allowed for *misty step*:

| Distance from Target | Teleport Height | Fall Damage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 30 | 3d6 |
| 10 | 25 | 2d6 |
| 15 | 25 | 2d6 |
| 20 | 20 | 2d6 |
| 25 | 15 | 1d6 |
| 30 | 0 | 0d6 |

Comment: Great answer! I have a couple of questions on additional details: how do you calculate the diagonal distance used to get into position above the target (do you disregard it, use standard rules for diagonal movement, use a table of trig distance, etc.)? And do you allow PCs to end in the same square as their targets or require them to have enough movement to end in a different square before attempting the maneuver?

Comment: @Upper_Case For *misty step* I've always just done a quick Pythagorean Theorem calculation. I'll add a table.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I like the addition of the calculation but you seem to be doing something odd with the rounding in the table beneath. If you're rounding then both 5 and 10 should be 30 (29.6 and 28.3 respectively)

Comment: @LioElbammalf Good eye. I rounded 28.6 down intentionally, so as to only give the full 3d6 when *misty step* is cast within 5 feet of the target.

Comment: Thank you both for the question and the answer. One of my players has been wanting to wild shape to a bird, then into a bear to attack an opponent, a la Beorn.

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that 5' squares are actually 5' cubes